# How to fix when Beautiful soup retrieving text content differently from the webpage?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data from JobsDB page of data analyst jobs using beautiful soup on python. I encountered a problem when I tried to retrieve the total number of listing data analyst job in Hong Kong. The number displayed on page is different from the number I retrieved.

Link to the page I used to scrape: https://hk.jobsdb.com/hk/search-jobs/data-analyst/1

I am sure that class "jabtvth" is unique and contains the total number of jobs on that page using inspect.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://hk.jobsdb.com/hk/search-jobs/data-analyst/"+str(1)
response = requests.get(url)
ret = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(ret, "html.parser")

totalPages = soup.find('span', class_ = "jabtvth").get_text()
print(totalPages)
```

On my most recent attempt, the number of data analyst jobs listing on the page was 175, while the result I got from parsing was 1865.

Comment: Are sure of the number 175? When I open the link which you have gave I see the number `1866`

Comment: Are you sure that it's not filtered when you view it in your browser? Have you tried viewing the page after clearing your cookies or using a new private/incognito window in your browser?

Comment: 1867 (which i get) is correct. It appears on the website

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is not scraping all the data. Check logs for errors or possible page duplicates.
On site pagination looks good. So I believe there's flaw somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and inspected the element in the webpage. There is only one line that has an attribute "jabtvth" (see below image). Seem like both the UI (1867) and the html code (1867) matches.

[image]